# How to show new View Controller when a Table View Cell is clicked in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to show a new view controller when a table view cell is clicked. But my problem is when I click table view cell the new view controller does not appear. I already have looked at solutions on SO but it didn't work.

Here is a screenshot of storyboard [image]

And here is the relevant code:

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellIdentifier: String = "restaurantCell"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "restaurantSegue" {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RestaurantInfoViewController") as! RestaurantInfoViewController
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

extension RestaurantTableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RestaurantTableViewCell

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "restaurantSegue", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Note: i also followed Apple's documentation in the link [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/handling_row_selection_in_a_table_view). But this didn't work as well

Comment: just remove the code for the "restaurantSegue" from the performSegue method.

Comment: You don't need to override the `prepareForSegue` method if you set up correctly the segue from the storyboard, here the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the screenshot the segue is connected to the table view cell.

If so delete `didSelectRowAt` because the segue is *performed* directly

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "restaurantSegue", sender: self)
}
```

The second issue is if you are using a segue you must **not** call `instantiateViewController`.

If you don't have to pass data to the next view controller you can even delete

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "restaurantSegue" {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RestaurantInfoViewController") as! RestaurantInfoViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Otherwise get the `destination` controller from the segue in `prepare(for` and use that.

If the segue is still not performed then there's something wrong with the identifier.

Comment: I did what you said but I still cannot go to destination view controller and I changed segue identifier name but that didn't work too. Also I should note that segue type is show if that makes a difference

Comment: Is `numberOfRowsInSection` really zero? Then of course nothing is displayed. Change it to `1` and later to  `<dataSourceArray>.count`

Comment: Found it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the `segue.destination` as your viewcontroller, no need to push it. The performSegue method will take care of it. Like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "restaurantSegue" {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            segue.destination =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RestaurantInfoViewController") as! RestaurantInfoViewController

        }
    }
```